# Reference only DataFrames where condidtion is True Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52625091/pandas-replace-the-value-of-a-column-in-dataframe-only-where-if-condition-is-tru) but somewhat different (and that answer did not work). I am trying to reference DataFrames where a condition is true. In my case, whether or not a word from a word bank is contained in the string. If the word is in the string, I want to be able to use that specific DataFrame later (like pull out the link if true and continue searching). So I have:

```py
wordBank = ['bomb', 'explosion', 'protest',
            'port delay', 'port closure', 'hijack',
            'tropical storm', 'tropical depression']

rss = pd.read_csv('RSSfeed2019.csv')
# print(rss.head())

feeds = []  # list of feed objects
for url in rss['URL'].head(5):
    feeds.append(feedparser.parse(url))
    # print(feeds)

posts = []  # list of posts [(title1, link1, summary1), (title2, link2, summary2) ... ]
for feed in feeds:
    for post in feed.entries:
        if hasattr(post, 'summary'):
            posts.append((post.title, post.link, post.summary))
        else:
            posts.append((post.title, post.link))



df = pd.DataFrame(posts, columns=['title', 'link', 'summary'])

if (df['summary'].str.find(wordBank)) or (df['title'].str.find(wordBank)):
    print(df['title'])
```

and tried from the other question...

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(posts, columns=['title', 'link', 'summary'])

for word in wordBank:
    mask = (df['summary'].str.find(word)) or (df['title'].str.find(word))
    df.loc[mask, 'summary'] = word
    df.loc[mask, 'title'] = word
```

How can I just get it to print the titles of the fields where the words are contained in either the summary or title? I want to be able to manipulate only those frames further. With current code, it prints every title in the DataFrame because *I THINK* since one is true, it thinks to print ALL the titles. How can I only reference titles where true?

Comment: Could you include a sample of posts?

Comment: See edit - left posts out because kinda long

Comment: I see but if you could include the first 10 or something or even a dummy example, will make it easier to verify if the solutions provided actually work as expected.

Comment: Oh mistake - I see what you are saying. Here is one:
`52 "Global TEU Breaks Record" https://www.porttechnology.org/news/global-teu-breaks-record/?utm_source=Feeds&utm_campaign=News&utm_medium=rss "The world’s total cellular containership fleet has passed 23 million TEU for the first time, according to shipping experts Alphaliner."`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the following setup:

```
posts = [["Global protest Breaks Record", 'porttechnology.org/news/global-teu-breaks-record/', "The world’s total cellular containership fleet has passed 23 million TEU for the first time, according to shipping experts Alphaliner."],
         ["Global TEU Breaks Record", 'porttechnology.org/news/global-teu-breaks-record/', "The world’s total cellular containership fleet has passed 23 million TEU for the first time, according to shipping experts Alphaliner."],
         ["Global TEU Breaks Record", 'porttechnology.org/news/global-teu-breaks-record/', "There is a tropical depression"]]

df = pd.DataFrame(posts, columns=['title', 'link', 'summary'])
print(df)
```

**SETUP**

```
                          title  ...                                            summary
0  Global protest Breaks Record  ...  The world’s total cellular containership fleet...
1      Global TEU Breaks Record  ...  The world’s total cellular containership fleet...
2      Global TEU Breaks Record  ...                     There is a tropical depression
```

You could:

```
# create mask
mask = df['summary'].str.contains(rf"\b{'|'.join(wordBank)}\b", case=False) | df['title'].str.contains(rf"\b{'|'.join(wordBank)}\b", case=False)

# extract titles
titles = df['title'].values

# print them
for title in titles[mask]:
    print(title)
```

**Output**

```
Global protest Breaks Record
Global TEU Breaks Record
```

Notice that the first row has `protest` in the title, and the last row has `tropical depression` in the summary. The **key idea** is to use a regex to match one of the alternatives in `wordBank`. See more about regex, [here](https://docs.python.org/3.7/howto/regex.html) and the documentation of [str.contains](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html).

Comment: Okay thank you - this does 99% of what I need. I have one small concern. Since you are extracting the titles, is that separating from the DataFrame? (not sure if I am asking that right) In other words, how can create new a new DataFrame with orignal data? Some like:
`for title in titles[mask]:
    hits = pd.DataFrame[titles[mask]]
    print(hits['link'])`

Comment: You can do df[mask] and that creates a new dataframe